# обработка текста в реакте из базы данных

Tags: reactjs

я получаю текст из базы данных, как его можно разбить по обзацам react?

Comment: `text.split('\n').map((parag)=><p>{parag}</p>)` (не забудьте указать key)

Comment: @xydope спасибо за помощь но я столкнулась ещё с такой проблемой : {pages[0].description.split('\n').map((parag)=><p key={parag}><h3>Schritt {step++}</h3>{parag}</p>)} один Schritt лишний. Как убрать ? Schritt 1 Schritt 2 Schritt 3 Schritt 4 Schritt 5 Schritt 6

Comment: у вас данные, скорей всего, заканчиваются переносом строки, поэтому и возникает лишний параграф. Просто сделайте проверку на пустоту параграфа.  `{pages[0].description.split('\n').map((parag)=> parag ? <p key={parag} ><h3>Schritt {step++}</h3>{parag}</p> : null)}`. P.s 1. Вместо `step++`, можно использовать индекс параграфа, map вторым аргументом принимает индекс `map((para, idx)=>{})` 2.тег `h3` неправильно помещать в тег `p`, лучше делать их на одном уровне и заворачивать в react.fragment `<><h3>header</h3><p>paragraph</p></>`.

Comment: @xydope спасибо большое, с проверкой работает, только вот не могу вывести кодом ваши два предложения. Может дадите какой нибуть пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: @xydope вот мой код: return (
    <>
    <ScrollToTop/>
    {pages && pages.length && (
     <Container fluid className="page">
      <h2 className="titel">{pages[2].name}</h2>
      <Row>
       <Col style={{ width: 700, height: 400 }}>
        <img 
        className="d-block w-100"
        src={pages[2].image} fluid
        alt={pages[2].name}/>
       </Col>

Comment: @xydope <Col className="ingred"><h2>Zutaten</h2>{pages[2].ingredients.split('\n').map((parag)=><p key={parag}>{parag}</p>)}</Col>
      </Row>
      <h2>Zubereitung</h2>
      <Row>
       <Col>
       {pages[2].description.split('\n').map((parag)=> parag ? <p key={parag}><h3>Schritt {step++}</h3>{parag}</p> : null)}
       </Col>
      </Row>
     </Container>
    )}
   </>
   );

Comment: Создайте новый вопрос и опишите в нем проблему.

Comment: @xydope прошу вас ещё раз помощь. Выводит ошибку: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop ```<Col>
       {pages[8].description.split('\n').map((parag)=><><h4>Schritt</h4><p key={parag}>{parag}</p></>)}
       </Col> ```

Comment: вы неправильно используете атрибут key. https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key